# Wordpress calculator form without resubmit and using custom field value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am currently trying to solve a problem on my Wordpress website. I do not have any code just yet (as I have re-written 4 different forms before I gave up), so I will just state what I want to do, I am pretty sure it's quite simple and I'm just missing something.

I need to build a form on the front-end that works like this: user inputs some value, chooses some other value from dropdown, than clicks on the submit button, page does NOT reload, instead a value is calculated and shown (I know how to show a value after click using jQuery), BUT the value that will be shown is calculated using not only form inputs and hardcoded variables, but also Wordpress custom field values using PHP function get_field().

The problem is that if I use ajax to get values from the form without reloading the page, those values are in javascript and I need to use them with PHP get_field() function.

So, to repeat what I intend to do, so It's easier to understand more quickly:

1. Form where user inputs some values
2. User clicks submit
3. **The page does not reload**
4. New value is calculated based on user input and custom field value (using get_field())
5. New DIV is shown using JQuery on submit click (I know how to do this one, but its important because this is the reason why the page must not be reloaded).

If you could just point me in the right direction, I will be able to code everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just inject the custom fields inside `javascript` variables when building the page template in `php`? Then you would have all the data available in `javascript` when the page loads. Something like this:

```
<?php

    echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var custom_field_1 = '.json_encode(get_field('custom_field_1')).';
            var custom_field_2 = '.json_encode(get_field('custom_field_2')).';

        </script>
    ';

?>
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know I could do that. And then I can just calculate the value inside javascript script and somehow print it in the div of my choice? I don't usually work with javascript but I think there isn't a classic echo like in php.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can use `$('div_selector_here').html('calculation_result_here')`. Would be nice to mark as accepted answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: I did! Thank you.